# NameNotFoundException while creating Ldap Entry with ldapTemplate.create

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I'm creating an application that needs to add a new ldap entry on OpenLdap, using spring-ldap (2.0.3) and an object-directory mapping specified using spring annotations.

I successfully managed to load a ldap entry with ldapTemplate.find(...), or to update with ldapTemplate.update(entry), but I can't create a new entry using ldapTemplate.create(entry). I obtain this exception :

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'uid=userId,ou=users,o=org'
```

My LdapTemplate is configured with a ldap base : "o=org"

And the LdapUser entry that a try to create looks like this :

```
@Entry(objectClasses = { "person", "top", ... }, base = "ou=users,o=org")
public final class LdapUser extends BaseAggregateRoot<String> {

    /** distinguished name, automatically build */
    @Id
    private Name dn;

    /** user id */
    @Attribute(name = "uid")
    @DnAttribute(value = "uid", index = 1)
    private String uid;
    ...
}
```

The Dn attribute is built automatically, and the value is correct (uid=userId,ou=users,o=org). BUT if I build it manually, ommitting the baseDN (uid=userId,ou=users), the creation is OK, but not the distinguished name for this entry.

Have you got any suggestions to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect to your LDAP using a LDAP browser , say Apache Directory Studio , and see what the DIT looks like ? Does it have ou=users,o=org ? And BTW your baseDN cannot be  "id=userId,ou=users" , like you mentioned , it can be ou=users,o=org or just o=org.

Comment: The DIT contains one baseDN : o=org, which contains many nodes, and ou=users is in. When I write "ommitting the baseDN (uid=userId,ou=users)", "id=userId,ou=users" is what I kept, so I ommit the baseDN o=org, and I keep only "id=userId,ou=users", and then the creation works.

Comment: That is fair as you have your  LdapTemplate is configured with a ldap base : "o=org". So what is the problem you are facing with it ?

Comment: My problem is that I expect to have the complete path as DN for my entry, so "uid=userId,ou=users,o=org" in my case. My entries contain "entryDN" attribute that is automatically initialized with the correct DN, with the complete path. So I'd like to be able to build my LdapUser Object (in Java) with the full path. I use it to initialize another entry. Maybe the problem is that I have a ldap base configured. but If i remove it, I have another error when loading Entries using ldapTemplate.find(query().where("uid").is(id), LdapUser.class). ==> [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]

Comment: I am not a Spring guy , but would suggest to find if there is a way for your entryDN auto-initialize to take into account LDAP base while geneating the DN.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I just found a link in spring-ldap doc concerning this point : http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#base-context-configuration. I will have to adapt their solution, since I don't use spring as IoC, but the solution is to have all my dn relative to the baseDN, and to prepend the baseDN to my new entry Dn to get a full DN, when needed ! I think this will not be very configurable as some of the dn path are specified in annotations ...